# Find nearby cities by a driving distance radius

Tags: distance, rest, driving

I'm studying GIS services to solve one specific need:

Given x/y coordinates of one city, I want a JSON result that lists only cities (not facilities) that are nearby the specified city, within a driving distance radius (e.g. 100km).

I came close to that with two: Geonames and ArcGIS, but I couldn't extract this kind of data on neither (maybe it's my lack of experience).

Do you know a service that I can use for this specific need? (I don't want map rendering). If possible, can you give a query example using it?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to provide details of the "several GIS tool" that you are already studying, please?  This helps us to not simply retrace your steps.  Also, our Q&A format works best with just one question per Question so perhaps think about whether you can focus this Question on one and research/ask the other separately.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for the tips! About the two questions, I believe the two are complementary, don't you?

Comment: For me two question marks means two questions so something like "Do you know a service, if possible with a query example, that I can use for this specific need?" would work better.  Using "service" in your first question, "tool" in your second question, and talking about "several GIS tools" made it harder to discern the number of questions.

Comment: I don't know about the JSON side of it, but in ArcGIS this sounds like either a simple select by location query (find all points within x distance of selected point) or possibly a network analyst service area problem (cities can *be* facilities) if actually considering a road network. I am unclear on what data you have and software you are using or have access to.

Comment: @ChrisW In ArcGIS I found how to locate nearby places: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/find-nearest.htm

But I didn't find the parameter to filter the result only to cities. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @ChrisW If you know how to do it to any output format, I believe that changing to JSON is easy...

Comment: Ah, I was not understanding the question and didn't realize the full implications of the REST tag (or what it even meant). After some reading I either conclude that 1) your real question is how to filter a query to or the results from an mapping service layer; or 2) you need to query against a layer that is only cities. In looking at the page you linked to, there are filter options as part of the layer input parameters (where clause), but without knowing the data you are querying (what attributes it has) I cannot suggest suggest anything specific.

Comment: @ChrisW I didn't understand what kind of atributes you're talking...I didn't choose a specific map service, I just came across the link I sent to you but I don't know how to make it work

Comment: I was under the impression you had tried Geonames and ArcGIS and gotten results, but your results included everything and not just cities. In the ArcGIS API you linked to, filtering to only city results would rely on querying against a dataset that had an attribute that defined 'type' - city, park, rest area, etc. As part of the `nearlayer` parameter, you would use the `"filter": [type] = "city"` or something to that effect. Or you would query against a dataset that was *only* cities. The API/service is only half the equation - you still need data to submit for it to process.

Comment: @ChrisW does this kind of dataset already exists in ArcGIS or do I have to create one?

Answer (score 4):

This service does what you describe in your original question -
Given x/y coordinates of one city, it returns a JSON that lists only cities (not facilities) that are nearby the specified city, within a given radius (e.g. 100km)
http://www.geobytes.com/get-nearby-cities-api/

As for an example - this link

```
http://gd.geobytes.com/GetNearbyCities?callback=?&radius=100&Latitude=-27.391701&Longitude=153.031006
```

Produces

```
?([["0.00","Chermside South","QL","Australia","North","0.00","AU","0.00","-27.391701","AUQLCSOT","153.031006","0.00","Queensland"],
["8.94","Chermside","QL","Australia","North","0.34","AU","0.63","-27.386101","AUQLCHER","153.031998","0.39","Queensland"],
["6.52","Chermside Centre","QL","Australia","North","0.47","AU","0.86","-27.384001","AUQLCCEN","153.031998","0.54","Queensland"],   
["176.96","Kedron","QL","Australia","South","1.00","AU","1.85","-27.408300","AUQLKEDR","153.031998","1.15","Queensland"],
["83.24","Wavell Heights","QL","Australia","East","1.02","AU","1.89","-27.389700","AUQLWHEI","153.050003","1.17","Queensland"],
["83.24","Wavell Heights North","QL","Australia","East","1.02","AU","1.89","-27.389700","AUQLWHNO","153.050003","1.17","Queensland"],
["318.61","Chermside West","QL","Australia","North-West","1.05","AU","1.94","-27.378599","AUQLCWEZ","153.018005","1.21","Queensland"]]);
```